# How get image filename from PHAsset of library in swift3

Tags: swift3, permissions, ios11, photo, photolibrary

I'm using QBImagePicker. I tried to get image file name, but it's very difficult. What can I do for that? I don't know it.

```swift
func qb_imagePickerController(_ imagePickerController: QBImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingAssets assets: [Any]!) {
    let requestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
    requestOptions.resizeMode = PHImageRequestOptionsResizeMode.exact
    requestOptions.deliveryMode = PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryMode.highQualityFormat
    // this one is key
    requestOptions.isSynchronous = true
    for asset in assets {
        if ((asset as AnyObject).mediaType == PHAssetMediaType.image) {
            PHImageManager.default().requestImage(for: asset as! PHAsset, targetSize: PHImageManagerMaximumSize, contentMode: PHImageContentMode.default, options: requestOptions, resultHandler: {
                (pickedImage, info) in
                self.selectImage.image = self.resizeImage(getImageView: self.selectImage, originImage: pickedImage!)
            })
        }
    }
    imagePickerController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if let fileName = Asset.value(forKey: "filename") as? String{

   print(fileName)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let originalName = PHAssetResource.assetResources(for: asset).first?.originalFilename
print("original File name \(originalName)")
```

Comment: Hi, please expand on your answer as to why this would be a solution to OP's issue. This will help OP and future visitors of the site. Thanks!